# Turn off setReadOnly action for one component inside binder

Tags: vaadin8

I have some components inside binder:

```
binder.bind(cbClientRating, Client::getRating, Client::setRating);
binder.bind(tfFirstName, Client::getFirstName, Client::setFirstName);
binder.bind(tfLastName, Client::getLastName, Client::setLastName);
binder.bind(dfBirthDate, Client::getBirthDate, Client::setBirthDate);
```

According my business logic i do not need to change **readonly** status for one component inside **binder**, for example Combobox - **cbClientRating** when i call  `binder.setReadOnly(false)`. It should be stay in readonly mode equal true.

Now i call 
`cbClientRating.setReadOnly(true)` after calling `binder.setReadOnly(false)`

`binder.setReadOnly(false);
 cbClientRating.setReadoOnly(true);`

Is there any other solution?

Comment: You could subclass `ComboBox` and override method `setReadOnly` but why do you need that behavior?

Comment: It seems that `binder.setReadOnly(false)` initially set one readonly state for combobox and then i set needed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code of `Binder#setReadOnly(boolean)`:

```
/**
 * Sets the read only state to the given value for all currently bound
 * fields.
 * <p>
 * This is just a shorthand for calling setReadOnly for all currently bound
 * fields. It means that fields bound after this method call won't be set
 * read-only.
 *
 * @param fieldsReadOnly
 *            true to set the fields to read only, false to set them to read
 *            write
 */
public void setReadOnly(boolean fieldsReadOnly) {
    getBindings().stream().map(BindingImpl::getField)
            .forEach(field -> field.setReadOnly(fieldsReadOnly));
}
```

So this is only a convenience method. I recommend that you handle the field read only states completly by yourself according to your business logic.